# Center of canvas in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I create an object in the center of the canvas, given that I need to input coordinates?

If it's possible, how can I get the coordinates for the center of the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

From [Bag of TK algorithms](http://wiki.tcl.tk/534) and also discussed in this [google mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/m5oxbmU_Jo8):

```
  toplevel .child
  set parent .
  set child .child

  # This should display $child centered in $parent
  set w [winfo width $parent]
  set h [winfo height $parent]
  set x [winfo rootx $parent]
  set y [winfo rooty $parent]
  set xpos "+[ expr {$x+($w-[winfo width $child])/2}]"
  set ypos "+[ expr {$y+($h-[winfo height $child])/2}]"

  wm geometry $child "$xpos$ypos"
```